# Arduino 5.0" TFT adn RA8875 driver issue

Tags: driver, arduino-uno, spi

Yesterday I got the shipment for my RA8875 driver and the 5.0" TFT display. I did some readings before the arrival of the driver and display and used the example programs in the libraries for some initial help. The TFT does not seem to be working for some reason. I did some troubleshooting by haveing some initialization commands in the Serial Monitor which stated the screen has been enabled and the RA8875 was detected.

These are my wired connections between the Arduino and the driver:
SCLK to UNO Digital #13 (Hardware SPI clock)
MISO to UNO Digital #12 (Hardware SPI MISO)
MOSI to UNO Digital #11 (Hardware SPI MOSI)
INT to UNO Digital #3
CS to UNO Digital #10
RESET to UNO Digital #9
VIN -> 3.3V
GND -> GND

I am really not sure if there is a problem with my wiring or the ribbon pin has some problems. Can someone help?

Here is the code from the examples :

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
#include "Adafruit_RA8875.h"


// Library only supports hardware SPI at this time
// Connect SCLK to UNO Digital #13 (Hardware SPI clock)
// Connect MISO to UNO Digital #12 (Hardware SPI MISO)
// Connect MOSI to UNO Digital #11 (Hardware SPI MOSI)
#define RA8875_INT 3
#define RA8875_CS 10
#define RA8875_RESET 9

Adafruit_RA8875 tft = Adafruit_RA8875(RA8875_CS, RA8875_RESET);
uint16_t tx, ty;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("RA8875 start");

  /* Initialise the display using 'RA8875_480x272' or 'RA8875_800x480' */
  if (!tft.begin(RA8875_480x272)) {
    Serial.println("RA8875 Not Found!");
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println("Found RA8875");

  tft.displayOn(true);
  tft.GPIOX(true);      // Enable TFT - display enable tied to GPIOX
  tft.PWM1config(true, RA8875_PWM_CLK_DIV1024); // PWM output for backlight
  tft.PWM1out(255);

  // With hardware accelleration this is instant
  tft.fillScreen(RA8875_WHITE);

  // Play with PWM
  for (uint8_t i=255; i!=0; i-=5 ) 
  {
    tft.PWM1out(i); 
    delay(10);
  }  
  for (uint8_t i=0; i!=255; i+=5 ) 
  {
    tft.PWM1out(i); 
    delay(10);
  }
  tft.PWM1out(255); 

  tft.fillScreen(RA8875_RED);
  delay(500);
  tft.fillScreen(RA8875_YELLOW);
  delay(500);
  tft.fillScreen(RA8875_GREEN);
  delay(500);
  tft.fillScreen(RA8875_CYAN);
  delay(500);
  tft.fillScreen(RA8875_MAGENTA);
  delay(500);
  tft.fillScreen(RA8875_BLACK);

  // Try some GFX acceleration!
  tft.drawCircle(100, 100, 50, RA8875_BLACK);
  tft.fillCircle(100, 100, 49, RA8875_GREEN);

  tft.fillRect(11, 11, 398, 198, RA8875_BLUE);
  tft.drawRect(10, 10, 400, 200, RA8875_GREEN);
  tft.fillRoundRect(200, 10, 200, 100, 10, RA8875_RED);
  tft.drawPixel(10,10,RA8875_BLACK);
  tft.drawPixel(11,11,RA8875_BLACK);
  tft.drawLine(10, 10, 200, 100, RA8875_RED);
  tft.drawTriangle(200, 15, 250, 100, 150, 125, RA8875_BLACK);
  tft.fillTriangle(200, 16, 249, 99, 151, 124, RA8875_YELLOW);
  tft.drawEllipse(300, 100, 100, 40, RA8875_BLACK);
  tft.fillEllipse(300, 100, 98, 38, RA8875_GREEN);
  // Argument 5 (curvePart) is a 2-bit value to control each corner (select     0, 1, 2, or 3)
  tft.drawCurve(50, 100, 80, 40, 2, RA8875_BLACK);  
  tft.fillCurve(50, 100, 78, 38, 2, RA8875_WHITE);

  pinMode(RA8875_INT, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(RA8875_INT, HIGH);

  tft.touchEnable(true);

  Serial.print("Status: "); Serial.println(tft.readStatus(), HEX);
  Serial.println("Waiting for touch events ...");
}

void loop() 
{
  float xScale = 1024.0F/tft.width();
  float yScale = 1024.0F/tft.height();

  /* Wait around for touch events */
  if (! digitalRead(RA8875_INT)) 
  {
    if (tft.touched()) 
    {
      Serial.print("Touch: "); 
      tft.touchRead(&tx, &ty);
      Serial.print(tx); Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(ty);
      /* Draw a circle */
      tft.fillCircle((uint16_t)(tx/xScale), (uint16_t)(ty/yScale), 4,         RA8875_WHITE);
    } 
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you didn't attach it to your VIN. Do that and you will be good.

Answer (score -1):

I think part of the reason for this problem might be because the tft needs 5V. I just checked the datasheet :p